# How to read and merge data from multiple CSVs in a folder based on specific column names in R program

Tags: r, csv, merge

I have 30 CSVs (with huge data) having 92 columns with headers, in a folder. I need to merge the data only for some specific 10 columns from all CSVs into a single df using r program. Lets say the column names as `Col1,Col2,Col3, COl4....Col10`. Below is my sample code ,which combines all the CSVs, irrespective to Column names.

```
mypath <-"C:/Blrt/B0/Mac/Output/"
setwd(mypath)
filelist <- list.files(path=mypath, pattern="*.csv", full.names=FALSE)
filelist
Almdat <- Reduce(rbind, lapply(filelist, read.csv,header=TRUE, quote = "",sep = ",",row.names = NULL))
```

Any support here pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a combination of purrr and readr from the tidyverse. read_csv from readr allows you to specific col_types and contains the function cols_only which allows you to specify which columns to load and the types you want them to be loaded as (the example below uses col_guess() but you can be more specific if you wish).

map_dfr from the package purrr replaces the lapply, Reduce and rbind. The result is a tibble combining the rows of all dataframes loaded.

```
library(tidyverse)

filelist <- list.files(path = "C:/Blrt/B0/Mac/Output/", pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE)

Almdat <- map_dfr(filelist, 
                  read_csv,
                  col_types = cols_only(Col1 = col_guess(),
                                        Col2 = col_guess(),
                                        Col3 = col_guess())
```

The example above uses only three columns, you can add as many as you like to you call to cols_only().

Comment: Hi Rory, I get warning of Delimiter or quotes , while executing your code. Also, I could see the number of Observations are less. Any fine tweaks ?

Comment: Hi @Rajhesh. That is strange. Are you able to post the exact warning you received? Regarding the number of observations issue, if you set the argument skip_empty_rows to FALSE, does the result have the expected number of rows?

Comment: hi@Rory. Seems those should be outliers / empty rows. Thanks. Your code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
cols <- paste0('Col', 1:10)
Almdat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(filelist, function(x) 
                  read.csv(x, quote = "",row.names = NULL)[cols]))
```

Or using `tidyverse` functions :

```
Almdat <- purrr::map_df(filelist, ~read.csv(.x, quote = "",row.names = NULL) %>% 
                                   dplyr::select(cols))
```

Comment: HI Ronak, I have column names like Date, Almid, history, Summary. Could you show me how to add those is Cols, as I get error as "undefined columns selected"

Comment: @Rajhesh In `cols` you need to include all the columns that you want to select. Something like `cols <- c('Date', 'Almid', 'history')`

Comment: Thansk Ronak, but while using purr::map_df code as above, it seems there is error as "Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  object 'x' not found"

Comment: @Rajhesh Sorry, that should be `.x`. I have updated the answer. Can you check that now?

Comment: somewhere i'm missing the part. it doesnt work for me. Thanks anyways for your support